# jQuery/javascript delete suffix of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables

I have a variable set to retrieve the id of a specific element which is "PubRecNum-1" (the number is also variable and will change depending on the record number).  What I'm needing is a way to only take the first 3 letters of the variable "Pub" (needed for comparison purposes).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get those letters using [`substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cz15ahb(VS.85).aspx) or [`slice()`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?q=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w1bzf9f(VS.85).aspx&sa=X&ei=I6kHTPv9I4H_4AbsxIyFAQ&ved=0CBoQzgQoADAA&usg=AFQjCNEzl1wC2lwPBP9EhrotqlKM4eN-Ew):

```
var str = "PubRecNum-1";
alert(str.substring(0, 3)); // -> "Pub"
alert(str.slice(0, 3)); // -> "Pub"
```

Comment: @sadmicrowave: yes, that would work fine.  As a general rule I would stick to using `slice` or `substring`, `substr` isn't part of the ECMAScript standard and its implementation differs between browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's [`substring()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) or [`substr()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) is used for exactly this

Comment: Note that the `substr()` is not part of the ECMAScript standard and its implementation varies between browsers.  Although `(0, 3)` as arguments would work the same across implementations, I prefer to avoid `substr()` altogether.